# Hide labels in a list depending if it ends with a substring with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show all the labels with the ending of 01 and hide the labels with out 01 at the end with jquery

I tried the following, but i'm unsure how to pass the following using jquery

```
$('.options li label:contains("' + $(this).endsWith("_01") + '")').show();
$('.options li label:contains("' + $(this).endsWith("!(_01)") + '")').hide();
```

Here's the sample i'm working with.

```
<ul class="options">
    <li><label>ENGLISH_03</label></li>
    <li><label>ENGLISH_02</label></li>
    <li><label>JAPANES_01</label></li>
    <li><label>CHINESE_05</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$('.options li label').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().endsWith("_01")
}).show();
```

```js
$('.options li label').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().endsWith("_01")
}).parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="options">
    <li><label>ENGLISH_03</label></li>
    <li><label>ENGLISH_02</label></li>
    <li><label>JAPANES_01</label></li>
    <li><label>CHINESE_05</label></li>
</ul>
```